# django: Cannot assign "8": "JobCalendar.claim" must be a "Claim" instance

Tags: django

I am trying to get one of my models to save to a calendar entry on save of my Claim model. I get:

> Cannot assign "8": "JobCalendar.claim" must be a "Claim" instance.

Claim Model:

```
class Claim(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        JobCalendar = get_model('jobs_calendars', 'JobCalendar')
        j = JobCalendar.objects.create(title=self.title, claim=self.id,
                                       tooltip='this is a tooltip', start='self.start')

        j.save()
        super(Claim, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '{}: {} {}'.format(str(self.id), self.claimant_firstname, self.claimant_surname)
```

Comment: Have you tried: `j = JobCalendar.objects.create(title=self.title, claim=Claim.objects.get(id=self.id), tooltip='this is a tooltip', start='self.start')`

Comment: That works thanks. If you want to put it as an answer I will mark it as answared. Thank You

Comment: Done and applied Sayse' suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

EDIT (thanks @Sayse):

```
 j = JobCalendar.objects.create(title=self.title, claim=self, tooltip='this is a tooltip', start='self.start')
```

Comment: This creates an extra sql query though, `claim=self` should be enough